# generate an overlay against a given image in OpenCV or Scikit-image

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

given an image, are there any ways to generate a grid that can be overlay against the original image. How to do it either in `OpenCV` or `scikit-image`?

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? Are you looking to generate a grid pattern?

Comment: Hi Hermes, yes, I would like to generate a grid pattern over the original image. Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at `drawPlanarBoard` ? what code or methods have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Like this. It should work with **scikit-image** and **OpenCV**, though you'll need to reverse the order of the colours for **OpenCV** as it uses BGR rather than RGB.

```
import numpy as np

spacing = 40

# Make black image
im = np.zeros((480,640,3), dtype=np.uint8)

# Draw grid
im[:, spacing:-1:spacing] = [0,0,255]    # red horizontal lines
im[spacing:-1:spacing, :] = [255,0,0]    # blue vertical lines
```

[image]